# Touch screen single figure or double finger gestures on inside specific window affect whole desktop - shouldn't do

Tags: window-manager, release-jolnir, touchscreen, gesture

Touch screen single figure or double finger gestures on inside specific window affect whole desktop.

Still 1 image. Single finger gesture stroke on specific window. I want this to scroll the contents inside the window. 2 fingers would be fine as well. But neither works:

[image: single finger gesture]

Still 2 image and that gesture results in a bird eye view zoom out of all windows. I don't want that, my finger is on a specific window.

[image: zoom out which I don't want following single finger gesture]

Panasonic FZ-G1 MkIII touchscreen.

In System Settings for Mouse & Touch there are only 3 settings and they are all for either 3 or more fingers, not for 2 and none for whole desktop gestures.

Video:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12x_tTmKejTaIGSpVS-OS7GvvwheU62bT/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded and got the [same issue](https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/1487). I worked around the issue by disabling the `touchegg` daemon from ever starting.

You can create the `/etc/systemd/system/touchegg.service.d/override.conf` file as follow, then reboot:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
Restart=

[Install]
WantedBy=
```

XDG will still autostart a touchegg client, but without the daemon it won't cause wreakage and let us use out touchscreen properly.